# Data not loading in GridView from Radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a code that I intend to use the radio button to retrieve data from a table and load it on a grid view. But once I click on the radio button , no data is loaded in the `GridView`. Below is my code:

```
protected void Radiobuttonlist1_CheckedChange(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Value = Radiobuttonlist1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

    if (Value == "Patients")
    {
        string connect = TraceBizCommon.Configuration.ConfigSettings.ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect);

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PatientName,PatientCellPhone from CustomerInformation", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else if(Value== "Suppliers")
    {
        string connect = TraceBizCommon.Configuration.ConfigSettings.ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect);

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select VendorName,VendorPhone from VendorInformation", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else if ( Value== "Employees")
    {
        string connect = TraceBizCommon.Configuration.ConfigSettings.ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmployeeName,EmployeeMobilePhone from PayrollEmployees", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}`
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `if`. What is the value of `Value`?

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of duplicate code, if you scope your if clause to your `SqlCommand`, instead of "everything".

Comment: "You could save yourself a lot of duplicate code, if you scope your if clause to your SqlCommand, instead of "everything" Marco how can i achieve this please

Comment: try to set `GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true ` and try again

Answer (score 2):

Since you have used [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to use the [`Tables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `DataSet`:

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Or like this:

```
da.Fill(ds,"tbl");
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl"];
```